# Creating a GLFW window with 10 bits color depth

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, nvidia, glfw

I am creatzing a window for OpenGL rendering with GLFW.I would like to use 10 bits color depth per channel to avoid color banding.

This is my code:

```
// Init GLFW
glfwInit();

// OpenGL 2.0
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);

// Use 10 bits
glfwWindowHint(GL_RED_BITS, 10);
glfwWindowHint(GL_GREEN_BITS, 10);
glfwWindowHint(GL_BLUE_BITS, 10);

// Create the window
auto window = glfwCreateWindow(mWindowWidth, mWindowHeight, "MyWIndow", monitor, NULL);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);



// Check if we are rendering at 10 bits
GLint redBits, greenBits, blueBits;

glGetIntegerv(GL_RED_BITS, &redBits);
glGetIntegerv(GL_GREEN_BITS, &greenBits);
glGetIntegerv(GL_BLUE_BITS, &blueBits);

// Nope, only 8 bits :-(
```

Sadly this does not work. The resulting OpenGL context is only 8 bits deep.

Should the above code work? Or have I made a mistake here?

Bonus question: does the display/monitor type matter? I have an Acer Predator X34p, which should be capable of 10 bits (8 bits + FRC). But in the NVIDIA control panel 10 bits are not available:

[image: NVIDIA control panel]

Can I still create a GLFW window/OpenGL context with 10 bits?

PPS: I'm using up to date NVIDIA drivers and a Geforce 2070, which should be capable of 10 bit rendering.

Comment: Here's an example using plain old OpenGL functions to create a 10-bit color context: https://github.com/j0r1/tenbit/blob/master/basic10bit.cpp. Try to get that working first, then look into how to make GLFW create it.

Comment: Do you use the _Game Ready Driver_ or _Studio Driver_? To my knowledge only the _Studio Driver_ is capable of 30 bit color.

Comment: @Erdal: That's not correct. 30bits support has been added to the GameReady drivers some time ago. See https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/gamescom-2019-game-ready-driver/

Comment: @Boris Thanks, it seems i am not up to date, but there was a time where that was the case, right?

Comment: @Boris Now i've read your linked article and yes (from the article): _"First introduced in our Studio Driver in July, our new Game Ready Driver adds support for 30-bit color across all product lines, including GeForce and TITAN..."_